# Merging pandas dataframes with 2 keys that are not the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I have these 2 tables :

```
tab1         tab2
col1 col2    col1 col2  col3
A    2017    A    2017  foo
A    2018    A    2019  fii
A    2019    A    2020  fee
B    2017    B    2017  boo
B    2019    B    2020  bii
C    2017    C    2017  coo
C    2018    C    2018  cii
```

I want to merge using Python these two tables with both `col1` and `col2` as keys. But my problem is, for example, on the second row, on tab1, I have (A, 2018) but on tab2, I have (A, 2019 or 2017) so the row will be `NaN` in the merged table.

So, my question is how can I fill those row by the nearest corresponding year from `tab2`? Instead of being an `NaN` row, it will be, for example, filled with (A, 2019).

So the result would be something like this :

```
merged_tab
col1 col2  col3
A    2017  foo
A    2018  fii
A    2019  fii
B    2017  boo
B    2019  boo
C    2017  coo
C    2018  cii
```

Thank you!

Comment: When you say nearest, does it matter for example if 2019/B gets mapped to `bii`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Here on the nearest previous value:

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(tab1.reset_index().sort_values(by='col2'),
                     tab2.sort_values(by='col2'),
                     on='col2', by='col1', direction='backward')
         .set_index('index').reindex(tab1.index)
      )
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2 col3
0    A  2017  foo
1    A  2018  foo  # 2018 is absent, let's take 2017
2    A  2019  fii
3    B  2017  boo
4    B  2019  boo
5    C  2017  coo
6    C  2018  cii
```

One the nearest following value:

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(tab1.reset_index().sort_values(by='col2'),
                     tab2.sort_values(by='col2'),
                     on='col2', by='col1', direction='forward')
         .set_index('index').reindex(tab1.index)
      )
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2 col3
0    A  2017  foo
1    A  2018  fii  # 2018 is absent, let's take 2019
2    A  2019  fii
3    B  2017  boo
4    B  2019  bii
5    C  2017  coo
6    C  2018  cii
```

Here on the nearest overall value:

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(tab1.reset_index().sort_values(by='col2'),
                     tab2.sort_values(by='col2'),
                     on='col2', by='col1', direction='nearest')
         .set_index('index').reindex(tab1.index)
      )
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2 col3
0    A  2017  foo
1    A  2018  foo  # 2017/2019 are equidistant, let's take 2017
2    A  2019  fii
3    B  2017  boo
4    B  2019  bii  # 2020 is closer than 2017
5    C  2017  coo
6    C  2018  cii
```

And if you want to merge on the nearest value, with the forward one in case of equality:

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(tab1.reset_index().eval('col2=-col2').sort_values(by='col2'),
                     tab2.eval('col2=-col2').sort_values(by='col2'),
                     on='col2', by='col1', direction='nearest')
         .set_index('index').reindex(tab1.index)
         .eval('col2=-col2')
      )
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2 col3
0    A  2017  foo
1    A  2018  fii  # 2017 and 2019 are equality distant, give 2019 priority 
2    A  2019  fii
3    B  2017  boo
4    B  2019  bii  # 2020 is closer than 2017
5    C  2017  coo
6    C  2018  cii
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I needed, with such details!!!